# enable/disable div on click

Tags: jquery, click, overlay

I want to enable an overlay `div` on click and disable it when it is clicked on.

Right now my code looks like this. Maybe the `.on .off` is used inappropriately?

```
$(function() {
    $("#sec_a_div").on("click","#wrapper_overlay");


    var docHeight = $(document).height();

    $("#wrapper_overlay")
      .height(docHeight)
      .css({
         'opacity' : 0.4,
         'position': 'absolute',
         'top': 0,
         'left': 0,
         'background-color': '#666666',
         'width': '100%',
         'z-index': 100
      })

    $.off("click","#wrapper_overlay");

});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? Wouldn't it be easier to have a global variable to check whether the `click` handler should be executed or not, rather than removing the event handler and adding it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want the following:

```
$(function() {
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var overlay = $("#wrapper_overlay")
      .height(docHeight)
      .css({
        'opacity' : 0.4,
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': 0,
        'left': 0,
        'background-color': '#666666',
        'width': '100%',
        'z-index': 100
      }).hide();

    overlay.on('click', function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#sec_a_div").on('click', function(){
        overlay.show();
    });
});
```

Understanding jQuery's `.on` and `.off` methods isn't that hard:

```
$(elementSelector).on(eventName, eventHandler);
$(elementSelector).off(eventName, eventHandler);
```

**Where:**

1. `elementSelector` could be anything from a CSS selector string to a collection of DOM objects or a earlier created jQuery selection.
2. `eventName` is the name of the event, could be one of the default (`click`, `mouseover`, `keydown`, etc.) or a custom event which is triggered by a `$(elementSelector).trigger(eventName);` call
3. `eventHandler` is a function executed when the event occurs, where the first argument given to this function is jQuery's event object.

And also

```
$(elementSelector).on('click', function(){
});
```

Is the same as

```
$(elementSelector).click(function(){
});
```

Comment: There are still some things that don't stick with me well, so thank you for your explanation. :)

Comment: Glad to help :) For the complete docs on `.on` and `.off` you should refer to: http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 2):

You may use `show()` and `hide()` to 'enable' and to 'disable' the overlay:

```
$("#sec_a_div").on("click", function() {
    $("#wrapper_overlay").show();
});

$("#wrapper_overlay")
  .height($(document).height())
  .css({
     "opacity": 0.4,
     "position": "absolute",
     "top": 0,
     "left": 0,
     "background-color": "#666666",
     "width": "100%",
     "z-index": 100,
     "display": "none"
  })
  .on("click", function() {
      $(this).hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off putting that CSS in a class

CSS

```
#wrapper_overlay
{
 opacity : 0.4;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #666666;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
 display:none;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#sec_a_div").on("click",function () { 
  $("#wrapper_overlay")
    .height($(document).height())
    .show();
});

$("#wrapper_overlay").on("click", function() { $(this).hide());
```